# Python: tqdm progress bar stuck at 0%

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I have written the following code to train a `bert` model on my dataset, I have used `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm` this import for `tqdm` and have used it in the loops. But when I run the program the bar stays at 0% even after the entire code has run. How to fix this?

### Code

#### Model

```
TRANSFORMERS = {
    "bert-multi-cased": (BertModel, BertTokenizer, "bert-base-uncased"),
}

class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model, num_classes=1):
        """
        Constructor
    
    Arguments:
        model {string} -- Transformer to build the model on. Expects "camembert-base".
        num_classes {int} -- Number of classes (default: {1})
    """
    super().__init__()
    self.name = model

    model_class, tokenizer_class, pretrained_weights = TRANSFORMERS[model]

    bert_config = BertConfig.from_json_file(MODEL_PATHS[model] + 'bert_config.json')
    bert_config.output_hidden_states = True
    
    self.transformer = BertModel(bert_config)

    self.nb_features = self.transformer.pooler.dense.out_features

    self.pooler = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(self.nb_features, self.nb_features), 
        nn.Tanh(),
    )

    self.logit = nn.Linear(self.nb_features, num_classes)

def forward(self, tokens):
    """
    Usual torch forward function
    
    Arguments:
        tokens {torch tensor} -- Sentence tokens
    
    Returns:
        torch tensor -- Class logits
    """
    _, _, hidden_states = self.transformer(
        tokens, attention_mask=(tokens > 0).long()
    )

    hidden_states = hidden_states[-1][:, 0] # Use the representation of the first token of the last layer

    ft = self.pooler(hidden_states)

    return self.logit(ft)
```

#### Training

```
def fit(model, train_dataset, val_dataset, epochs=1, batch_size=8, warmup_prop=0, lr=5e-4):
    
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

    optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
    
    num_warmup_steps = int(warmup_prop * epochs * len(train_loader))
    num_training_steps = epochs * len(train_loader)
    
    scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer, num_warmup_steps, num_training_steps)

    loss_fct = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='mean').cuda()
    
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        model.train()
        start_time = time.time()
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        avg_loss = 0
        
        for step, (x, y_batch) in tqdm(enumerate(train_loader), total=len(train_loader)):
            
            y_pred = model(x.to(device))
            
            loss = loss_fct(y_pred.view(-1).float(), y_batch.float().to(device))
            loss.backward()
            avg_loss += loss.item() / len(train_loader)

            xm.optimizer_step(optimizer, barrier=True)
            #optimizer.step()
            scheduler.step()
            model.zero_grad()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
                
        model.eval()
        preds = []
        truths = []
        avg_val_loss = 0.

        with torch.no_grad():
            for x, y_batch in tqdm(val_loader):                
                y_pred = model(x.to(device))
                loss = loss_fct(y_pred.detach().view(-1).float(), y_batch.float().to(device))
                avg_val_loss += loss.item() / len(val_loader)
                
                probs = torch.sigmoid(y_pred).detach().cpu().numpy()
                preds += list(probs.flatten())
                truths += list(y_batch.numpy().flatten())
            score = roc_auc_score(truths, preds)
            
        
        dt = time.time() - start_time
        lr = scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]
        print(f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{epochs} \t lr={lr:.1e} \t t={dt:.0f}s \t loss={avg_loss:.4f} \t val_loss={avg_val_loss:.4f} \t val_auc={score:.4f}')

model = Transformer("bert-multi-cased")
device = torch.device('cuda:2')
model = model.to(device)

epochs = 3
batch_size = 32
warmup_prop = 0.1
lr = 1e-4

train_dataset = JigsawDataset(df_train)

val_dataset = JigsawDataset(df_val)
test_dataset = JigsawDataset(df_test)
fit(model, train_dataset, val_dataset, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, warmup_prop=warmup_prop, lr=lr)
```

### Output

`0%|          | 0/6986 [00:00<?, ?it/s]`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The import should be:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

The error is in the training function, correct this loop:

```
for x, y_batch in tqdm(val_loader, total = len(val_loader)):
```

Comment: In theory OP used the correct import for Jupyter. which is `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm` instead of `from tqdm import tqdm` (which would result in the progress bar printing on new lines)

Comment: @Ishan answers is correct. If you're not using jupyter, do not import from tqdm.jupyter.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to Ishan Dutta answer, `tqdm.notebook.tqdm` (and not `tqdm.tqdm`) is the correct function to use for both Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab.

This problem can happen if you don't have ipywidgets installed or if you have installed ipywidgets before installing JupyterLab.

What fixed it for me was reinstalling ipywidgets:

```
pip3 uninstall ipywidgets --yes
pip3 install --upgrade ipywidgets
```