# Python: Text Classification with BERT stuck at 0%

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, bert-language-model, transformer-model

Being new to text classification, I was playing with [kaggle data](https://www.kaggle.com/abhishek/aaamlp/version/1?select=imdb_folds.csv) named `imdb_folds.csv`, and then the running of my code got stuck while showing this message:

```
0%|                                      | 0/1250 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
```

My is code is:

```
## Import Packages
import tez
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import transformers
from transformers import AdamW, get_linear_schedule_with_warmup
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd

## Create a data loader using a class named BERTDataset 
class BERTDataset:
    def __init__(self, texts, targets, max_len = 64):
        self.texts = texts
        self.targets = targets
        self.tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(
            "bert-base-uncased", #model name
            do_lower_case = False
        )
        self.max_len = max_len
        
    # length function
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.texts)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        text = str(self.texts[idx])
        inputs = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
        texts,
        None,
        add_special_tokens = True,
        max_length = self.max_len,
        padding = "max_length",
        truncation = True
        )
        resp = {
            "ids": torch.tensor(inputs["input_ids"], dtype = torch.long),
            "mask": torch.tensor(inputs["attention_mask"], dtype = torch.long),
            "token_type_ids": torch.tensor(inputs["token_type_ids"], dtype = torch.long),
            "targets": torch.tensor(self.targets[idx], dtype = torch.float),
            
            ## for multiclass classification, convert change dtype from torch.float to torch.long
            #"targets": torch.tensor(self.targets[idx], dtype = torch.long),
        }
        return resp

## Build the model
class TextModel(tez.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_classes, num_train_steps):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.bert = transformers.BertModel.from_pretrained(
            "bert-base-uncased", return_dict = False
        )
        self.bert_drop = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.out = nn.Linear(768, num_classes) # num_classes is 1 or > 1 if it is binary multiclass classification respectively
        self.num_train_steps = num_train_steps
        
        
    # optimizer
    def fetch_optimizer(self):
        opt = AdamW(self.parameters(), lr = 1e-4)
        return opt
    
    # scheduler
    def fetch_scheduler(self):
        sch = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(
            self.optimizer, num_warmup_steps = 0, num_training_steps = self.num_train_steps        
        )
        return sch
    
    # loss
    def loss(self, outputs, targets):
        return nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(outputs, targets.view(-1, 1))
    
        ## include the next line if you have multiclass classification 
        # return nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(outputs, targets)
    
    # calculate accuracy
    def monitor_metrics(self, outputs, targets):
        outputs = torch.sigmoid(outputs).cpu().detach().numpy() >= 0.5
        
       
        targets = targets.cpu().detach().numpy()
        return {"accuracy": metrics.accuracy_score(targets, outputs)}
    
    # forward function
    def forward(self, ids, mask, token_type_ids, targets = None):
        _, x = self.bert(ids, attention_mask = mask, token_type_ids = token_type_ids)
        x = self.bert_drop(x)
        x = self.out(x)
        if targets is not None:
            loss = self.loss(outputs, targets)
            met = self.monitor_metrics(outputs, targets)
            return x, loss, met
        return x, 0, {} # if there is no target, return 0        


## Read Dataset
def train_model(fold):
    df = pd.read_csv("imdb_folds.csv") # read file
    df_train = df[df.kfold != fold].reset_index(drop=True)
    df_valid = df[df.kfold == fold].reset_index(drop=True)
    
    train_dataset = BERTDataset(df_train.review.values, df_train.sentiment.values)
    valid_dataset = BERTDataset(df_valid.review.values, df_valid.sentiment.values)
    
    # n_train_steps = int(len(df_train) / TRAIN_BS * EPOCHS)
    n_train_steps = int(len(df_train) / 32 * 10)
    model = TextModel(num_classes = 1, num_train_steps = n_train_steps)
    
    es = tez.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor = "valid_loss", patience = 3, model_path = "model.bin")
    model.fit(
        train_dataset, 
        valid_dataset = valid_dataset, 
        device = "cuda", 
        epochs = 10, 
        train_bs = 32,
        callbacks = [es],
    )
    
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    train_model(fold = 0)
```

I found similar problem on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67506630/python-tqdm-progress-bar-stuck-at-0) but could not adapt the solution. Any help to fix this ll be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried smaller batch_size? e.g 1 @William

Comment: Thanks @meti. I reduced the batch size, but still same problem. I use Windows 10 computer with 64GB RAM, and GPU Nvidia Quadro P2200.

Comment: Isn't `model.fit()` tensorflow's function???